# How to unit test a custom logger which is a wrapper around tracesource object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, logging, trace

I have a wrapper around TraceSource class. I'm wondering how can I unit test it. Since I need to configure app.config file in order to add trace listeners to TraceSource object, add SwtichSource etc. So would it be valid to manually add app.config file in unit test dll and configure it to do unit testing? I know we can progrmatically do all this but the way I have created a wrapper around TraceSource it looks quite ticklish or may be impossible. Any suggestions will be more than welcome.

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{

    private const int ERROR_EVENT_ID = 2;
    private const int DEBUG_EVENT_ID = 5;
    private  static TraceSource source;

    public Logger(string nameOfComponent)
    {
         source = new TraceSource(nameOfComponent);
    }

    public  void LogDebug(string message, string methodName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(methodName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("message, methodName can't be null or empty");

        source.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, DEBUG_EVENT_ID);
    }

    public  void LogError(string methodName, Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(null, methodName, ex);
    }

    public  void LogError(string message, string methodName, Exception ex)           {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(methodName) || ex == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("message, methodName and exception can't be null or empty");

        source.TraceData(TraceEventType.Error, ERROR_EVENT_ID, message, methodName, ex);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having this class create a `TraceSource` for itself, inject the `TraceSource` into it via constructor injection. That way, in your unit tests, you can initialize the TraceSource with listeners that let you record what has been done to it.

You should also make sure your `source` field is not static, since it's getting initialized by the non-static constructor and is used by non-static methods.

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior shall I go for dependency injection for injecting tracesource instance to Logger constructor?

Comment: And will dependency injection work for a multithreaded scenario?

Comment: And the important thing is that each class that accesses Logger class to do tracing/logging. I need that class' name and I'm not sure if I will be able to do so if I inject tracesource into Logger class' constructor through Dependency Injection? As TraceSource constructor will have name of the class like TraceSource source = new TraceSource("name of class where tracing/logging is happening").

Comment: @user2913184: you can have two constructors: one like I'm describing, and the other says: `public Logger(string nameOfComponent) : this(new TraceSource(nameOfComponent))`. That way, you can inject the TraceSource when you need to (for unit testing, e.g.), but still have an easy-to-use constructor for initializing static instances.

Comment: @user2913184: The reason you've given for using a static field here doesn't work. What will end up happening is that all of your Logger instances will use the most recent `TraceSource` that was created, so they'd all claim to be coming from the most recently-initialized component. The choice to use a static logger belongs in the classes that consume this class.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior if I force classes using my Logger to create a static field like static ILogger logger = new Logger("name of class logging"); Then only a single instance of TraceSource will be created and used by all the threads since CLR will initialize static logger field once and then it will be shared among all the threads. Does this make sense to you.

Comment: If I replace static with readonly then I have to have a static constructor in my Logger class. Rather I'm thinking of initializing a static instance of Logger object (which will be done by CLR) wherever we need to do tracing/logging (by calling LogDebug,LogError methods etc). Then that instance will be shared by all the threads and whatever lying inside Logger object at global level will also be shared no matter whether it's static or not. So I would take StriplingWarrior point to make source field as nonstatic as it will be shared anyway if threads share static instance of Logger.

Comment: So basically all you saying that I shouldn't force those classes using my Logger to explicitly create a static instance of it. Rather leave it up to the classes. But in case I force classes to create a static instance by doing so ILogger logger = new Logger("name of class logging"); Then it will definitely work but then classes won't have any choice.

Comment: I did Logger class public Logger(TraceSource traceSource) {source = traceSource;}public Logger(string nameOfComponent):this(new TraceSource(nameOfComponent)){source = new TraceSource(nameOfComponent);}  And in my unit test class something like. static TraceSource source = new TraceSource("TestingClass");  private ILogger AddCustomTraceListener(){ ILogger log = new Logger(source);          CustomDBTraceListener listener = new CustomDBTraceListener();          source.Listeners.Add(listener); source.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Verbose; return log;}And then AddCustomTraceListener().LogDebug(...);

Comment: Further if i do this in Logger class TraceSource ts;public Loger(TraceSource ts){ this.ts = ts} public TraceSource(string className):this(new TraceSource(className){ this.ts  = new TraceSource(className)}. May be I can do just with the first constructor itself and don't need to second one. Since any class which is going to instantiate my logger will have to explicitly declare TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("classname"); So I will end up getting classname from here itself and just pass the ts object to first constructor above as I don't require second ctor to pass in the class name explicitly

Comment: @user2913184: WRT your comments from 2 days ago, since you want each Logger instance to have different state (e.g. class name) associated with it, making that state `static` won't work. You want the constructor to initialize *instance-specific fields*, and a static constructor cannot take any arguments. Technically, you could do some trickery with generic types, since you'd have a different static initialization and state for each generic argument, but that would put you back into a situation where it's difficult to unit test, and it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: @user2913184: WRT your comment from yesterday, the nice thing about the second constructor is that it avoids the repetition of `new TraceSource(...)` in every class. Also, to avoid having your class names get out of sync with the code, you might want to either have a constructor that takes a `Type` argument so you can use `typeof()`, or if you're using C# 6 you can use the `nameof()` operator.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior WRT your comment number 1 (2 days ago). I want to make it little clearer that when i say that I will put static ILogger log = new Logger("name of class that gonna use logger in it"); at global level,what I really mean that each and every class which is gonna use Logger to log messages is going to have this static initialization at it's individual global level.And as you said static ctor doesn't take argument (well I know that really well). But I couldn't understand where the static ctor came from.I didn't mention anything about static ctor as far as Logger class is concerned.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior when I put the static initializer like static ILogger log = new Logger("name of class that gonna use logger in it"); in each class let's say  ClassA and ClassB. Even if the call from within ClassA's method goes to ClassB's method I observed that for both the classes I do get different state (e.g. class name). Since now I'm using  public Logger(string nameOfComponent) : this(new TraceSource(nameOfComponent)) so I don't have to pass new TraceSource(nameofclass) as you said.And I also made the other ctor as private like private Logger( TraceSource tracesource){ts = tracesource;}

Comment: @StriplingWarrior it's getting really confusing for me now. Can you please reply by writing some solid code? So that I can clearly understand what you are trying to put across and make sure we are on the same page.I appreciate all your help till now.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior also I couldn't understand what do u mean by class names getting out of sync.And where do you want me to use `typeof()`.As i earlier said it's getting really confusing please reply with some code.

Comment: @user2913184: Sorry to confuse you. You're probably doing just fine if you just make `private TraceSource source` non-static. The other things are not that important.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say unit test, and unit tests (as opposed to acceptance or integration tests) should not reach outside to external components including the OS, I'm presuming you're wanting to test the logic of this class but aren't interested in testing that the log messages actually make it out to their destination (file or DB or cloud or whatever).

If so, then a solution is to wrap the `TradeSource` class in a very thin wrapper that has no logic (and therefore no need to unit test).  This would allow you to easily inject it or create it with a factory, mock it, and therefore unit test the logic in the Logger class.  Something like so:

```
public class TraceSourceLogTarget : ITraceSourceLogTarget
{
    private TraceSource _traceSource = new TraceSource();

    ...

    public void TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType, int eventId)
    {
        _traceSource.TraceEvent(eventType, eventId);
    }

    ...
}
```

I personally would make an interface that is even more generic (like `ILogTarget`) and have it be implementable by other logging frameworks if you change your mind and ensure you're not tightly coupled to this one, but to get going, this would work.

Comment: No actually I'm trying to test both the class logic/functionality as well as logging logs to oracle database.

Comment: @user2913184 Well then it's not a unit test, it's an integration or acceptance test.  http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/  "Runs in memory (no DB or File access, for example)"

Comment: Agreed. It's gonna be an integration test.